# Proof of the Lebesgue Density Theorem in $\Bbb{R}^n$

Tags: measure-theory, reference-request, lebesgue-measure

I am looking for a simple proof of the Lebesgue density theorem for $\Bbb{R}^n$. The Wikipedia page on the [Lebesgue differentation theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lebesgue_differentiation_theorem) leads me to a proof of that more general theorem, but mentions that there are simpler proofs of the density theorem giving a reference to the book *Measure and Category* by Oxtoby. Because of the pandemic, I don't have access to a library just now and I can't find a simpler proof online except for the case $n = 1$. Can anyone point me to a source that is accessible online.

Note that [where to find a proof of the Lebesgue Density Theorem](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/39090/where-to-find-a-proof-of-the-lebesgue-density-theorem) asks about the general case, but the answer leads to a broken link to a paper by Faure. If that was Faure's paper in the American Mathematical Monthly from February 2002, then it only covers the case $n = 1$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As commented in your other [post](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/383664/simple-proof-of-the-lebesgue-density-theorem-in-bbbrn), the proof of the Lebesgue density theorem from the book *Measure and Category* by Oxtoby, refers to case $n = 1$, despite being in the chapter regarding $r$-Spaces. The author also suggests the [article](https://doi.org/10.1080/00029890.1979.11994796) *An Elementary Proof of the One-Dimensional Density Theorem*, which as the title suggests, also refers to the $1$ dimensional case.

About the Faure's paper it actually refers to the $1$ dimensional case. I will be leaving two links to this article. [Link 1](http://alpha.math.uga.edu/%7Epete/Faure02_Lebesgue_Density.pdf) -- [Link 2](https://doi.org/10.1080/00029890.2002.11919854).

As [Bruno Stonek](https://math.stackexchange.com/users/2614/bruno-stonek) commented in the post you left referenced, the $n$ dimensional case is left as an exercise in the book Real Analysis: Modern Techniques and Their Applications by Folland, more precisely, the exercise 3.4.25.

A reference to the $n$-dimensional case would be the book *Geometry of Sets and Measures in Euclidean Spaces* by Mattila, the Lebesgue density theorem is the Corollary 2.14 in page 38, where the author uses the Lebesgue differentiation theorem to prove it. Another interesting reference is The Lebesgue Density Theorem in Abstract Measure Space by Miriam Yevick which can be found at this [link](https://dspace.mit.edu/bitstream/handle/1721.1/85715/28370877-MIT.pdf).

On the Lebesgue differentiation theorem, I suggest, chapter 11 of the book *Measure Theory and Integration* by Taylor. I will reference the [article](https://doi.org/10.1080/00029890.2003.11920024) *An Elementary Proof of Lebesgue's Differentiation Theorem* by Botsko and [this](https://math.aalto.fi/%7Ejkkinnun/files/real_analysis.pdf) pdf.

I will present the Folland exercise solution.

---

> If $E$ is a Borel set in $\mathbb{R}^n$, the density of $E$ at $x$ is defined as,
>
> $$D_E (x) = \lim_{r\to 0} \frac{m(E\cap B(r,x))}{m(B(r,x))}$$
> whenever the limit exists.
>
> Show that $D_E (x)=1$ for a.e. $x\in E$ and $D_E (x) = 0$ for a.e. $x \in E^{c}$

Define $\mu:\mathcal{B}_{\mathbb{R}^n}\to [0,\infty]$ by $\mu(A)=m(E\cap A$), this is a measure and the Lebesgue-Radon-Nikodym representation is $d\mu=\chi_E\, dm$.

Let $A\in\mathcal{B}_{\mathbb{R}^n}$ and suppose $m(A)<\infty$. Given $\varepsilon\in (0,\infty)$, there exist a open set $U\subseteq\mathbb{R}^n$ containing $A$ such that $m(U)<m(A)+\varepsilon$ and hence $m(U\setminus A)<\varepsilon$. It follows that

$$\mu(U)=m(E\cap U)\le m(E\cap A)+m(U\setminus A)<\mu(A)+\varepsilon$$

Given $A\in \mathcal{B}_{\mathbb{R}^n}$ and $\varepsilon\in (0,\infty)$, chose a sequence $\{A_k\}_k$ of Borel sets such that $m(A_k)<\infty$ fo all $k\in\mathbb{N}$ and

$$\bigcup_{k=1}^{\infty} A_k = A$$

For each $k\in\mathbb{N}$ there exist a open set $U_k\subseteq\mathbb{R}^n$ containing $A_k$ such that $\mu(U_k)<\mu(A_k) + 2^{-k}\varepsilon$. We have,

$$A\subseteq\bigcup_{k=1}^{\infty} U_k\quad\text{and}\quad \mu \left(\bigcup_{k=1}^{\infty} U_k\,\setminus A\right)<\varepsilon$$

This implies that $\mu(A)=\inf\{\mu(U) : U\subseteq\mathbb{R}^n\text{ is open and } A\subseteq U\}$. Therefore $\mu$ is regular, so for almost every $x\in\mathbb{R}^n$

$$D_E (x) = \lim_{r\downarrow 0} \frac{m(E \cap B(r,x))}{m(B(r,x))}=\lim_{r\downarrow 0} \frac{m(B(r,x))}{m(B(r,x))}=\chi_E (x)$$

In particular, $D_E (x)= 1$ for almost all $x\in E$ and $D_E(x)=0$ for almost all $x\in E^{c}$.

Comment: I have now been reading Folland. May I ask a couple of questions about your last chain of equations. Firstly, is $m$ in the numerator of the second faction a typo for $\mu$? Secondly, are you appealing to the theorem that immediately precedes this block of questions? Or is there some way of seeing the last equation that doesn't depend on the Lebesgue differentiation theorem?